# Is it valid to run t-test on interpolated vectors - if so, how to adjust alpha?

Tags: t-test, p-value, data-imputation, interpolation

**The task:** I need to calculate a one-sample t-test to see if the mean of a vector of values differs significantly from zero.

**Data:** The dataset consist of about 25 such vectors, each with a length of 19 (counts collected at different points in time). So there's the small sample problem, but additionally, some data from these vectors (up to 10-20%) are missing. However, since the vectors are essentially transformed trendlines, it seems it would be possible to linearly interpolate the missing values prior to the transformation.

*Edit to answer comments about data:* each of the 25 vectors (or rows of a table, or samples, if you will) are conceived the following way: counts of certain occurrences of X and Y were observed on 19 consequtive occasions, and normalized so that each value of a vector reflects the propertion of X (vs Y) at that time point when the observation was made (so they are in essence trends of X). The values in these trend vectors were then further transformed (the function itself is irrelevant here, and a bit too involved). But this yields those vectors; the null hypothesis is that their mean is 0, the alternative is that it is not 0.

```
Proportions of X over time:
x = 0.05 0.09 0.11 0.13 0.14 0.16 0.22 0.23 0.23 0.24 0.34 0.26 0.29 0.37 0.40 0.34 0.48 0.53 0.46
Transformed into:
xtr = 0.36  0.14  0.11  0.03  0.08  0.24  0.03 -0.01  0.04  0.27 -0.17  0.07  0.21  0.05 -0.12  0.31  0.09 -0.13 (element at first position gets removed in the process)
```

One sample t-test of xtr yields p-value of 0.01993; if vector x is interpolated to length 50, the p-value of the t-test on the transformed vector is 0.00005278.

**Problem:** I am not sure how to intepret the p-values after that though: the more interpolation I add (used the `approx` function in R), the more significant results I get - starting with 3 significant (alpha=0.05) out of 25 at no interpolation and only interpolating missing; but going up to 14-17 out of 25 with p<0.05 results, if adding more interpolated datapoints; but interestingly with not much increases when getting up to 180-200 interpolated points. The plot below (going in increments of 10 interpolated points) illustrates this.

[image: interpolated]

How to make sense of that? On the one hand, the data collection was done in a sparse manner across time, so it is reasonable to assume there *could* be more data in there (if the data were collected more frequently and by doing a broader sweep out there) - this makes intepolation tempting, particularly in cases where there seems to be a qualitatively pretty straightforward upward or downward trend (just with gaps in some places, or just being too small samples in general). Then again, if I add too much, almost each test becomes "significant".

**Question:** Is there some (justifiable) middleground here - would it be valid to use (some justifiable amount of) interpolation prior to a t-test, and if so, should I (somehow) reconsider the alpha threshold for significance?**

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask whether the mean of a vector (or set of vectors) "is significantly different from zero": it either is zero or not.  Statistical significance attaches to a *hypothesis test* about some *model parameter.*  What is your model?  For instance, many people would model counts with Poisson distributions.  But then, observing a single nonzero count would be completely convincing evidence ($p=0$) that the Poisson parameter (its *mean*) is nonzero.

Comment: I think you're getting more significant results because interpolated values are inherently less noisy. One solution might be to not use a deterministic function for the missing data, and to instead add a random error term. With suitable chosen variance for the error term the number of significant results wouldn't change. You could also use multiple imputation, and draw on the relationship between all observed consecutive data points to impute the missing data.

Comment: @whuber why would you ever make a distributional assumption to test a mean??

Comment: @PaulB Because "test a mean" has absolutely no meaning without some kind of distributional assumption.  The word "mean" in this phrase refers to a property of a distribution; if no distribution is posited, there is nothing to test.

Comment: @whuber if I randomly sample enough individuals from a population, and I want to test the null hypothesis that the population mean is zero, no distributional assumptions need to be made.

Comment: @PaulB I'm afraid that's simply not true.  You might not be making *explicit* assumptions, but any test you care to apply will be making *some* assumptions, of which the most important is that there even is a "population"! (You might be confusing "distributional assumptions" with "adopting a parametric model.") In the present case, this question is worded so vaguely and ambiguously that it's not even clear what the data are, much less how they are being conceived of as a sample of some population or process.

Comment: @whuber I agree the the question isn't sufficiently specific, but I still don't understand your claim to having to choose the distribution, e.g., Poisson or Gaussian, which I referred to as a distributional assumption. I think with a random sample of sufficient size from a well defined population we can make inferences about the population mean by appealing to the central limit theorem. I suppose we have to assume the mean and variance are defined? is that what you mean by distributional assumption?

Comment: @PaulB Yes, that's an example of an implicit assumption that is often made. The present case offers a stark example of why distributional assumptions are important: if you assume *any* possible distribution supported on the natural numbers $0,1,2,\ldots$ and want to test whether its mean is zero, then a good test statistic is the sum of the observations and the critical region for rejecting the null is all counts of $1$ or greater. This is a trivial observation, to be sure, but it seems to address perfectly the situation described in this question.

Comment: Interesting points here; I added further explanation about the data along with an example, hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: @user3554004 Did you sample these data from some population? E.g., did you randomly determine when or where the counts were made? If so, you have a missing data problem (why are the data missing?), and your method of imputation is reducing the overall variance in the count variable. There are lots of options for imputing data. If instead this is not a random sample, you have nothing to test, as whuber notes.

Comment: @PaulB data is sample from a population (text corpus, which itself is a sample of language (population of words) for some period Z), yes, 19 times across uniform intervals. The missing points are those when neither word X nor word Y could be found, so the proportion is missing/NA. So the data is "small" in two ways: the text corpus is that big itself (a small sample of the larger language population) and the number of counts across time (19) is pretty small as well (one for each decade) - counting more/shorter intervals would make the proportions more unreliable.

Comment: @user3554004 gotcha. In that case my thinking of this as a missing data problem was incorrect. I think whuber's thinking was right though that the population mean can't possibly be zero, since the ratio can't be negative, and you observe positive ratios. Given your small samples whuber I think is also right that you have to assume a distribution, since you can't appeal to asymptotic with that small sample. A t-test can't be correct, since the outcome can't be normally distributed.

Comment: @PaulB the underlying count data indeed cannot be negative (being proportions of X in the sample of counts of X and Y), but the transformed data (on which the t-test is to be applied) can and often does have negative values - and tends to be normally distributed ('ish, given the small number of values) - so yes, the population mean can very well be zero; the alt.hypothesis is that it is not, however.